# Отключение «Please remove the installation medium, then press Enter»

Tags: linux, ubuntu, live-usb

Как известно, Ubuntu при выключении LiveCD/LiveUSB выдаёт такое сообщение:

[image]

Есть ли возможность отключить это? Мне будет нужно перезагрузить компьютер по удалёнке (я поднял себе SSH в загруженном LiveUSB), и нажать Enter будет просто некому.

Comment: добавьте `noprompt` к опциям, передаваемым программе *linux*. см. например, [здесь](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbiquityAutomation#Available_preseeding_keys)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin для этого нужно вырубить уже загруженный liveusb, а в моём случае это невозможно, можно без перезагрузки как-нибудь?

Comment: изменить `/proc/cmdline` не получится: только для чтения. но можно попробовать изменить «на лету» код, который обрабатывает наличие/отсутствие этой опции: https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/tree/bin/casper-stop (см. переменную `prompt`). например, можно создать файл `/run/casper-no-prompt`.

Comment: нажимать на enter по окончании установки, кстати, вовсе не обязательно. можно просто перезагрузить компьютер. эффект будет аналогичный.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. можно добавить `noprompt` к параметрам, передаваемым программе *linux*
2. в уже работающей системе можно создать файл `/run/casper-no-prompt` или поправить код прямо в [соответствующем файле](https://git.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/tree/bin/casper-stop) `casper`-а. искать файл надо где-то в недрах каталога `/casper` (или куда там монтируется/копируется casper-овское «хозяйство» в вашей сборке). хотя имя довольно уникальное — можно и начиная с корня поискать.

Comment: Беда пришла откуда не ждали: liveusb-флешку тронули, она перестала контачить и системные файлы вместе с `/sbin/casper-stop` тупо перестали читаться :D Пришлось перезагружаться через `echo -n b > /proc/sysrq-trigger` благо ssh не отвалился :) Но в виртуалке проверял — `touch /run/casper-no-prompt` действительно работает